# Bounty Auto-Answer Selected the Wrong Answer?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/128468/3gb-ram-installed-and-detected-by-bios-windows-vista-32bit-only-sees-2gb) about a month ago and opened a bounty on it last week. Of all of the answers given none of them correctly solved the problem so I never accepted one. Now that the bounty is over the system auto-selected an answer with 2 votes, instead of selecting another answer with 9 votes. What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That answer was posted before the bounty was set, which makes it ineligible to be auto-selected.

You can see the rules surrounding bounties in the [Bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) question.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. Auto-accepted answer was definitely not a winner- and neither was the highest voted one, but it *was* of a substantially higher quality.